# Split array into chunks based on timestamp in Haskell

Tags: arrays, haskell, split, aggregate

I have an array of records (custom data type) in Haskell which I want to aggregate based on a each records' timestamp.  In very general terms each record looks like this:

```
data Record = Record { event :: String, 
                       time :: Double, 
                       from :: Int, 
                       to :: Int 
                     } deriving (Show, Eq)
```

I used a Double for the timestamp since that is the same format used in the tracefile.

And I parse them from a CSV file into an array of records: `[Record]`

Now I'm looking to get an approximation of instantaneous events / time.  So I want to split the array into several arrays based on the timestamp (say. every 1 seconds) and then fold across each smaller array.

The problem is I can't figure out how to split an array based on the value of a record.  Looking on Hoogle I found several functions like `splitEvery` and `splitWhen`, but I'm lost.  I considered using `splitWhen` to break up the list when, say, `(mod time 0.1) == 0`, but even if that worked it would remove the elements it's splitting on (which I don't want to do).

I should note that the records are NOT evenly spaced in time.  E.g. the timestamp on sequential records is not going to differ by a fixed amount.

I am more than willing to store the data in a different format if you can suggest one that would make this sort of work easier.

A quick sample of the data I'm parsing (from a ns2 simulation):

```
r 0.114 1 2 tcp 1000 ________ 2 1.0 5.0 0 2
r 0.240 1 2 tcp 1000 ________ 2 1.0 5.0 0 2
r 0.914 2 1 tcp 1000 ________ 2 5.0 1.0 0 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `[Record]` and you want to group them by a specific condition, you can use `Data.List.groupBy`.  I'm assuming that for your `time :: Double`, 1 second is the base unit, so `time = 1` is 1 second, `time = 100` is 100 seconds, etc, so adjust this to whatever system you're actually using:

```
import Data.List
import Data.Function (on)

isInSameClockSecond :: Record -> Record -> Bool
isInSameClockSecond = (==) `on` (floor . time :: Record -> Integer)
-- The type signature is given for floor . time to remove any ambiguity
-- due to floor's polymorphic type signature.

groupBySameClockSecond :: [Record] -> [[Record]]
groupBySameClockSecond = groupBy isInSameClockSecond
```

Comment: Thanks! I wound up doing (roughly): `isInChuck t1 t2 = 0.1 > abs (t1 - t2)`, since I wanted to group with more granularity than that.  This definitely sent me down the right path though.

Comment: @user2494447 That's what I was aiming for.  I didn't think this solution would work directly out of the box for you since I wasn't quite sure how you were representing time, but I hoped seeing `groupBy` in action would push you in the right direction.